# Regex matching only string with no alphanumeric prefix

Tags: regex, grep

Is there some quick way how to write egrep regex that accepts something in this format:

(some characters or nothing but NOT numbers and alphabet characters)black

```
black and white
    black is good color
blackeverywhere
9black cats
```

it should accept first and second line

EDIT: Maybe I should be more precise, after black must be some spaces and black doesnt have to be in the beginning

this is a valid one

```
   a i o black    fdfd
```

these are not

```
ppooo pblack sdsdds
iii blackdsdsd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated based on new examples**

More precise:

`(\s|^)black(\s|$)`

1. `(\s|^)` match either a space or start of a new line
2. `black` literal string match
3. `(\s|$)` match either a space or end of line

Comment: There is no string that `\s*` will not match, even things without spaces at all. That means that 9black will be matched. Oops! I do not think that that star is your friend.

Comment: Whoops my bad. Removed the * :)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly

```
$ grep "\bblack\b" file
black and white
    black is good color

$ ruby -ne 'print if /\bblack\b/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
(\s|^)black(\s|$)
```

This should match any space or nothing at the beginning, followed by any space or nothing at the end.

It sounds like you simply want black to be isolated in the string ... surrounded by spaces, tabs, or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

One of these might work

`/(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])black(\s|$)/`
`/(^|[\W_])black(\s|$)/`